# datastax c# driver IEnumerable<T> foreach optimize

Tags: cassandra, driver, datastax

I am using CassandraCSharpDriver 3.0.4 version. I need to mapreduce my table. I run 24 parallel query and take 24 IEnumerable lists. Then I concate 24 IEnumerable list to one IEnumerable list. Those steps do not takes much time. It is about 10 seconds.

The problem starts when I start to foreach codes for the combined IEnumerable which has 10M records. It takes about 15 minutes. It does not matter if I use  Parallel.Foreach.

I use Mapping feature, Linq feature of the driver. In some way, I need to optimize mapping system, may be doing something manuel or doing something parallel. I need suggestions. By the way, I am aware of other solutions for mapreduce. I need exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot time, and testing both linq and plain session execute, i figured out what caused that. Just running execute method takes number of pagesize rows. If you want to iterate result it takes whole rows. In my case, pagesize was 5000  and  whole row count is 1.5M that is why iteration takes too much time.